# How to customize insert query in MS BI?

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence

I need to customize insertion query, in an Integration Service project. how can I do it?

Comment: That's a pretty vague question. Can you give some details about what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to write you own SQL for the Insert then you can use the Execute SQL Task.